# How to execute js function when the view is changed on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 views in my Angular2 app one for Login and one for Register
the problem is when I use some styles like Datatable or iCheck it's applied only if I access to the page directly and when I go by routes it's not rendered, because the style need to execute JS function every time the view is changed

this is the js function

```
$(function () {
  $('.iCheck').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
  });
});
```

here is some pictures of the issue

when I go to the link directly the checkbox is styled

[image]

when I go to login page by the clicking on the link below

[image: when I go to login page by the clicking on the link below]

and again if I refresh the same page the style work again 
[image]

And this is the index page where the js function defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <base href="/">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Starter</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/adminlte/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
        page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
        apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect.
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/adminlte/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<sc-root></sc-root>
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="assets/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.iCheck').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you call the js method on ngOnInit of the component that will do the trick . ngOnInit is invoked everytime a component is rendered

Comment: i want it to be global

Comment: then make it global on your injectable service